# Sex with a Non-Mehram in Dream?

Tags: sex, nocturnal-emission

Sometime we see in dreams that doing sex with a non mehram woman and when we wake up find a viscus liquid in trousers. So it will be counted in Gunah? As we all know we see in dream everything even which are not possible in real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a type of wet dream, you need to **do ghusl** after it but it is **not a sin** since you can not control yourself while asleep. Wet dreams are quite natural and it is a sign of **puberty**.

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "The Pen is lifted from the minor, the insane person and the sleeper."
>
> - https://sunnah.com/urn/1263610
> - https://sunnah.com/nasai/27/44
> - https://sunnah.com/urn/1263600